# Error returned when trying to enumerate through worksheets in workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to enumerate through sheets in workbooks, returns error in Excel VBA.

My code -

```
     For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
            myFile = objFile.Name

            MsgBox ("File --> " & myFile)
            MsgBox ("Error: " & Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description)

            Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Open(objFile.Name)
            MsgBox ("Error in opening Workbook(s): " & Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description)
            
            DoEvents
            

            With wb
                
                wb = ActiveWorkbook
                MsgBox ("Error in beginning looping of workbook: " & Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description)
                
                For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
                   
                    MsgBox ("Error in beginning For - Next: " & Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description)
                
                Next


            End With


     Next objFile
```

Trying to execute this in a function returns an error in the For - Next loop. The error returned is `Object variable or With block variable not set`.

EDIT -

This is the full code that I have -

```
Option Explicit

Function LocateCellString1(rng As Range) As Variant
       'Declare the variables
            Dim objFSO As FileSystemObject
            Dim objFolder As Folder
            Dim objFile As File
            Dim strPath As String
            Dim strFile As String
            Dim NextRow As Long

            Dim intCount1 As Integer
            Dim searchStr As String
            Dim wb As Workbook
            Dim ws As Worksheet
            Dim Loc As Range
            Dim myPath As String
            Dim folderPath As String
            Dim myFile As String

            'Application.Volatile
            Application.ScreenUpdating = False

 

On Error Resume Next
'========================================================================

 

If (rng.Cells.Count > 1) Then
    LocateCellString1 = "Invalid function call"
    Exit Function
End If
'========================================================================

 

 

        folderPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
        'myPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName
        myPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Name

        'Target Path with Ending Extention
        searchStr = rng.Cells(1, 1).Value
        intCount1 = 0


    '================

        'Specify the path to the folder
        strPath = folderPath

        'Create an instance of the FileSystemObject
        Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")


        'Get the folder
        Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strPath)

        'If the folder does not contain files, exit the sub
        If objFolder.Files.Count = 0 Then
            MsgBox "No files were found...", vbExclamation
            Exit Function
        Else
            'MsgBox ("Files found: " & objFolder.Files.Count)
        End If


    '================

 

 

    
     For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
            myFile = objFile.Name

'            If myFile = myPath Then
'                MsgBox ("Same file " & myFile & " : " & myPath)
'                GoTo LoopOn
'            ElseIf myFile = ("~$" + myPath) Then
'                MsgBox ("Same file " & ("~$" + myPath) & " : " & myFile)
'                GoTo LoopOn
'            End If

            MsgBox ("File --> " & myFile)
            MsgBox ("Error: " & Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description)

            Set wb = Workbooks.Open(objFile.Name)
            MsgBox ("Error in opening Workbook(s): " & Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description)
            DoEvents

            With wb
                For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
                MsgBox ("Error in initiating For - Next loop: " & Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description)
                    MsgBox ws.Name & " in " & wb.Name
                    MsgBox ("Error in displaying sheet name: " & Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description)
                Next
                wb.Close
            End With

     Next objFile

 

 

    'LocateCellString1 = intCount1 - 1


        If (intCount1 - 0) > 0 Then
            LocateCellString1 = "Integrated"
        Else
            LocateCellString1 = "Not Integrated"
        End If

 

 

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Volatile

 

End Function
```

**EDIT #2 - [Using Sub instead of Function]**

> Sub Sub1()
> 'Declare the variables
> Dim objFSO As FileSystemObject
> Dim objFolder As folder
> Dim objFile As file
> Dim strPath As String
> Dim strFile As String
> Dim NextRow As Long
>
> ```
>         Dim intCount1 As Integer
>         Dim searchStr As String
>         Dim wb As Workbook
>         Dim ws As Worksheet
>         Dim Loc As Range
>         Dim myPath As String
>         Dim folderPath As String
>         Dim myFile As String
>
>
>         Dim strAlert1 As String
>         
>         'Application.Volatile
>         Application.ScreenUpdating = False
>
>
>
>     On Error Resume Next
>     
>     folderPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
>     'myPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName
>     myPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Name
>
>     'Target Path with Ending Extention
>     searchStr = rng.Cells(1, 1).Value
>     intCount1 = 0
>
>
> '================
>
>     'Specify the path to the folder
>     strPath = folderPath
>
>     'Create an instance of the FileSystemObject
>     Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
>
>
>     'Get the folder
>     Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strPath)
>
>     'If the folder does not contain files, exit the sub
>     If objFolder.Files.Count = 0 Then
>         MsgBox "No files were found...", vbExclamation
>         Exit Sub
>     Else
>         'MsgBox ("Files found: " & objFolder.Files.Count)
>     End If
>
>
> '================
>
>
>  For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
>         MsgBox ("objFile here is: --> " & objFile)
>         MsgBox ("Error: " & Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description)
>
>             Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Open(objFile.Name)
>             MsgBox ("Error in opening Workbook(s): " & Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description)
>             
>             DoEvents
>     
>     wb.Close
>     Set wb = Nothing
>  Next objFile
> ```
>
> End Sub

Comment: Remove `wb = ActiveWorkbook` it is not necessary as your alredy set `wb` when opening the workbook. Also: you would have to use `Set wb = ActiveWorkbook`

Comment: Try `Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Open(objFile.Path)`

Comment: Still returns the same error - Object variable or With block variable not set

Comment: Just seen your edit and the full code ... are you using this in a Worksheet Function (ie you are using it in a cell in a Worksheet)? If so, it won't work ... you can't open other Workbooks in a Worksheet Function. If you go to the Function in the code editor and run it directly (i.e. place the cursor anywhere within it and press F5) then it will work ... but not in a Worksheet Function.

Comment: Quite right, I was trying to run it in a worksheet function. Should I be going the "Sub" procedure way then?

Comment: Have used 'Sub' instead. Now returns another error -  Error number: 424. Error Description: Object required. 

The code that I rewrote is in the next Edit of my post above.

Comment: Where is `rng` defined ? I suggest you remove `On Error Resume Next` otherwise you won't see all the errors.

Comment: Am able to view the errors at the required points.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, which assumes that all files in `objFolder` are Excel Workbooks.

```
    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        Dim wb As Workbook
        Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Open(objFile.Name)
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
            MsgBox ws.Name & " in " & wb.Name
        Next
        wb.Close SaveChanges:=False ' optionally close the Workbook you just opened
     Next objFile
```

If you have already `Dim`med `wb As Workbook` and `ws As Worksheet` previously in your code then remove those lines from my code.

> UPDATED CODE FURTHER TO COMMENTS FROM OP

Sounds like the code is failing to open a particular file (are all files in the folder Excel Workbooks?) which means that the `wb` variable does not hold a reference to a valid Workbook (and so, likely, is `Nothing`) and when it is asked for its collection of Worksheets (this is what the `For Each ws In wb.Worksheets` line is doing) then there is an error.

Try this code (replace my previous code with this) which will first test if the file is an Excel Workbook and, if not, show an appropriate dialog AND if the file is an Excel Workbook but for some reason cannot be opened then will show an appropriate dialog for that. It will then show a dialog for each Worksheet in each open-able Workbook.

```
For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
    If StrComp(Right$(objFile.Name, 5), ".xlsx", vbTextCompare) = 0 Or _
            StrComp(Right$(objFile.Name, 5), ".xlsm", vbTextCompare) = 0 Or _
            StrComp(Right$(objFile.Name, 4), ".xls", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
        Dim wb As Workbook
        Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Open(objFile.Name)
        If wb Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Could not open file " & objFile.Name
        Else
            Dim ws As Worksheet
            For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
                MsgBox ws.Name & " in " & wb.Name
            Next
            wb.Close SaveChanges:=False ' optionally close the Workbook you just opened
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "File " & objFile.Name & " is not an Excel Workbook"
    End If
Next objFile
```

Comment: Still returns the same error - Object variable or With block variable not set

Comment: On which line in the error?

Comment: The line - "For Each ws In wb.Worksheets"

Comment: Although the files in the folder are Excel files and Excel macro workbooks, the code returns that none of those could be opened.

Answer (score 0):

Try the modified version below, explanation within the code's comments:

```
' - define object and variable outside the loop -
Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
Dim myFile As String

For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
    myFile = objFile.Name
    
    If InStr(myFile, ".xls") > 0 Then   ' <-- make sure current file in Excel type

        ' -- not sure why you need these MsgBox popping
        MsgBox ("File --> " & myFile)
        MsgBox ("Error: " & Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description)
        
        ' trap possible erros in opening Excel file
        On Error Resume Next
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(myFile)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If wb Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox ("Error in opening Workbook(s): " & Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description)
        
        Else
            ' -- Again - not sure why you need these MsgBox popping
            MsgBox ("Error in beginning looping of workbook: " & Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description)
            
            With wb
                For Each ws In .Worksheets
                    MsgBox "Worksheet name '" & ws.Name & "' in Excel file '" & .Name
                Next ws
            End With
            
            ' - close file and clear object -
            wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
            Set wb = Nothing            
        End If
    
    End If
Next objFile
```

Comment: Still returns the same error - Object variable or With block variable not set

Comment: @europtaifun on which line ?

Comment: The line - "For Each ws In wb.Worksheets"

Comment: @europtaifun did you even try this code? since I don't have a line `For Each ws In wb.Worksheets`, I am using a `With` statement a line before

Comment: That has been tried. Did not work.